# Automation error (vba)

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, recordset

I have an issue with Automation error when I try to run my code in VBA. My ADODB connection is declared as public in a module so that I could use the same connection for several SQL statements.

My 1st SQL statement and recordset('rs1') works fine but my 2nd recordset('mainRS') gave me an Automation error and I'm not sure which part went wrong.

Can anyone help, please? Thank you!!

```
Public Sub MainConDef(DBPath As String)                  'DBPath as global
    Set dsConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")     'dsConnect, cmdCommand, rs declared as global
    Set cmdCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    dsConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & _
      ";JET OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx" & ";Mode=Read|Write"

    dsConnect.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    dsConnect.Open

    With cmdCommand
        .ActiveConnection = dsConnect
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblManhours;"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    With rs1
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open cmdCommand
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i, j, k As Integer

    DBPath = "D:\DbManHours.accdb"
    MainConDef (DBPath)

    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1

    OverallData (DBPath)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Sheet2.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset mainRS

    mainRS.Close

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub OverallData(DBPath As String)
    Dim cmd1 As Object

    Set cmd1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set mainRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")       'mainRS declared as global

    dsConnect.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    If Not (dsConnect Is Nothing) Then
        If (dsConnect.State = adStateClosed) Then dsConnect.Open
    End If

    cmd1.ActiveConnection = dsConnect
    cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblManhours" & _
        "WHERE tblManhours[Dept No]=OPS" & _
        "AND tblManhours[Dept No]=FIN" & _
        "AND (tblManhours[Type]) NOT IN ('F', 'N')"

   Set mainRS = cmd1.Execute    '<-- Automation error occurs here

   Sheet2.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset mainRS

   mainRS.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Missing spaces in the SQL, e.g you end up with `tblManhoursWHERE` although I would not think that would raise that specific error.

Comment: You are using late binding (CreateObject) so unless you have added a reference to the ADODB library all enums like adUseClient don't have the correct values.  Consider early binding & option explicit.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. I think it might be caused by a combination of errors. It works after I changed it to early binding, change my sql statements to "SELECT * FROM tblManhours WHERE [Dept No] in ('OPS', 'FIN')" and define the rs cursor properties. Although I'm not completely sure of the reasoning behind it.